# Do Block Breakers retain Redstone Energy Cell power?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tekkit

Thinking about making a system that will, after fully charging a Redstone Energy Cell, remove the block and place another empty one in it's place to eliminate any wasted energy from the running engines.  I was thinking about using [Block Breakers](http://wiki.technicpack.net/Block_Breaker), but I'm worried it won't keep the energy stored if I use that.

Comment: Open up a creative world and just try

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.

The block breaker imitates a user's left click, not sneak + left click with a Crescent Hammer, which is needed to retain the stored energy.

[This youtube video shows the results of breaking a redstone energy cell by a block breaker.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JzNGgJJgX4I)

Answer (score -2):

it will keep energy that is stored

Comment: no it won't. simple as that